# docker compose I want use my local directory C:/html for /var/www/html

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose

Hello I want to publish the  "index.php" from the local folder "C:\html\index.php" with docker-compose.yml

in localhost I get the typical apache html "It works". But I do not get the content of my local folder. What I am doing wrong?

here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
 
services:
 
  # --- MySQL 5.7
  #
  mysql:
    container_name: "dstack-mysql"
    image: bitnami/mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
  php:
    container_name: "dstack-php"
    image: bitnami/php-fpm:8.1
  

 
 
  # --- Apache 2.4
  #
  apache:
    container_name: "dstack-apache"
    image: bitnami/apache:2.4
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    depends_on:
      - php
   
  volumes:
    - C:/html:/var/www/html
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: "dstack-phpmyadmin"
    image: bitnami/phpmyadmin:latest
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - '81:8080'
      - '8143:8443'
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=host.docker.internal
volumes:
  dstack-mysql:
    driver: local
```

Update:

volumes:
- ./html:/var/www/html

Doesn't works.

I want to have a web development docker environment where I edit in the folder C:\html\index_hello.html in my computer and I will see the changes in the browser localhost:8080, the changes I did. My expectation is that I write in the browser http://localhost:8080/index_hello.html. Did I something wrong? shall I edit other files e.g. apache.conf?

Comment: Looks like you need to indent the volumes key to line up with the rest of the keys for the apache container.

Comment: The `php-fpm` container itself starts a webserver. Try debugging it first before adding httpd image... More specifically, your PHP files should be mounted in it, not Apache image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest avoiding hardcoding directories and using relative directories.

If you place your docker-compose into your C:/html folder and then change your volume to read:

```
volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
```

if you run the following:

```
cd C:/html
docker-compose up -d
```

you are telling docker-compose to use `.` meaning the current directory.

if you put the `docker-compose.yml` in the C:/ directory you can run change the volume to:

```
volumes:
    - ./html:/var/www/html
```

then the docker compose command should remain the same.

Comment: I don't think you can mount the folder where the compose file exists. Or if you can, that wouldn't be recommended as then the HTTP server would be able to render the content of the compose file.

Comment: Yes. That's why I gave the example of how to do a relative mount while it is not in the folder.